# How to exlude certain word on regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a text document that I need to modify. Most of the words are seperated by "-" (minus) character.

So in sublime text, I tried this pattern:

`(\w+)\-(\w+)`

This pattern works perfectly fine but there is one word that has "-" (minus) character naturally in the document. (Eg: foo-bar)

So I need a pattern that finds all minus seperated words but exludes "foo-bar"

Sorry if this question asked before but I couldn't find the answer I needed

Comment: try to give the first preference to the user who posted the first working answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead (with optional `i` switch to match words in a case-insensitive way):

```
(?i)(?!\bfoo\-bar\b)\b(\w+)-(\w+)\b
```

Mind that this will only work with non-overlapping matches.

See example:

[image]

If you want to replace a hyphen with space in cases I provided in the screenshot, you can use `(?!\bfoo\-bar\b)\b(\w+)\-(?=\w)` search regex and replace with `$1` (result: `go there now`):

[image]

Comment: What is there is also another words that I want to exclude?

Comment: Add them inside parentheses: `(?!\b(?:foo-bar|new-word|another-word)\b)`